# Cloud-init related error on ec2 ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: server, python, amazon-ec2

I am getting below errors on my EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 server. If anyone knows the reason and solution please help me.

When I tried `Cloud-init status` I got `status: error` as a result.

The error log shown below is from `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`:

```
Cloud-init v. 19.4-33-gbb4131a2-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 running 'init-local' at Fri, 01 May 2020 13:12:14 +0000. Up 8.38 seconds.
2020-05-01 13:12:14,988 - util.py[WARNING]: failed stage init-local
failed run of stage init-local
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 653, in status_wrapper
ret = functor(name, args)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 323, in main_init
init.fetch(existing=existing)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/stages.py", line 352, in fetch
return self._get_data_source(existing=existing)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/stages.py", line 253, in _get_data_source
util.del_file(self.paths.instance_link)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1793, in del_file
raise e
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1790, in del_file
os.unlink(path)
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/var/lib/cloud/instance'
------------------------------------------------------------
Cloud-init v. 19.4-33-gbb4131a2-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 running 'init-local' at Fri, 01 May 2020 18:10:43 +0000. Up 8.08 seconds.
2020-05-01 18:10:43,999 - util.py[WARNING]: failed stage init-local
failed run of stage init-local
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 653, in status_wrapper
ret = functor(name, args)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 323, in main_init
init.fetch(existing=existing)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/stages.py", line 352, in fetch
return self._get_data_source(existing=existing)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/stages.py", line 253, in _get_data_source
util.del_file(self.paths.instance_link)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1793, in del_file
raise e
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1790, in del_file
os.unlink(path)
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/var/lib/cloud/instance'
```

**Currently, the server is working.**

ubuntu@host:~$ sudo cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}

network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 02:9e:ef:ad:39:1a
            set-name: eth0
    version: 2

ubuntu@host:~$ ls -lah /etc/netplan/
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K May 18 04:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 117 root root  12K Jun  2 06:32 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  481 Jun  1 09:51 50-cloud-init.yaml

ubuntu@host:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 02:9e:ef:ad:39:1a
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=vif ip=172.31.1.160 link=yes multicast=yes
```

=========Solution i did on other server as showing below============

```
ref. link = https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/faq.html

$ sudo DI_LOG=stderr /usr/lib/cloud-init/ds-identify --force
$ sudo cloud-init clean --logs
$ sudo cloud-init init --local
$ sudo cloud-init init

@heynnema Below  the output of cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

root@ip-172-31-1-135:/# cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        ens5:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 02:69:72:f4:1e:aa
            set-name: ens5
    version: 2
```

Comment: Has this EC2 ever worked for you? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: please check @heynnema

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: sorry for the late reply.
I had no courage for changing things in a live server.
so after seeing your reply in a post today, I have decided to resolve this issue in another server(dev server) which is having same issue.
so I finally found below command for resolving this issue.

$ sudo DI_LOG=stderr /usr/lib/cloud-init/ds-identify --force
$ sudo cloud-init clean --logs
$ sudo cloud-init init --local
$ sudo cloud-init init

Comment: Where did you find those commands? Please edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: Thank you Heynnema for pushing me for resolving this issue, now all logs are showing properly after reboot and during commands execution.
I am sharing solution link 
https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/faq.html

Comment: Please do show me the current .yaml. Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: That's the same .yaml as your original, except for the different ethernet interface name and MAC. I don't see what changed.

Comment: .yaml file is not changed but my private IP change and its reinitialize configuration in /var/lib/cloud/
root@ip-172-31-1-135:/# cloud-init status
status: done

Comment: The IP changed due to `dhcp4: true`. Otherwise, I don't understand why it's working, as my understanding is that AWS EC2 requires bridging, as per my answer. Oh well, I'm glad it's working for you.

Comment: how do you know if he server is using a bridge connection or not?
I have only one ethernet connection on all EC2 with LO.

Comment: `ifconfig` would show the bridge, probably as device br0, or something similar. I'd contact Amazon Support and ask them about the bridge requirement.

Comment: just checked on two servers and I found eth0 and lo on one server and ens5 and lo on the second server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that AWS EC2 requires bridging. Please try this .yaml file. Keep the exact spacing, indentation, and no tabs, as netplan is very fussy.

**Note**: keep a backup copy of your current .yaml file, just in case.

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
        macaddress: 02:9e:ef:ad:39:1a
      set-name: eth0
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      macaddress: 02:9e:ef:ad:39:1a
      interfaces:
        - eth0
```

---

**Note**: You may need to create `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg`

```
network: {config: disabled}
```

---

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot` # mandatory

**Update #1:**

OP found below commands for resolving this issue...

```
$ sudo DI_LOG=stderr /usr/lib/cloud-init/ds-identify --force 
$ sudo cloud-init clean --logs 
$ sudo cloud-init init --local 
$ sudo cloud-init init
```

Source: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/faq.html